# Creation process in C++ in regards to member variables and constructor call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor

I'm running into a strange error when a constructor is called for one of my classes. Essentially, what I'm doing is this:

I have a class "A", that has two member variables of type "B", "C". "C" *has* to be initiated with a member of type "B". So the constructor has to be:

```
A::A():
c(b)
{}
```

This works fine if the class is laid out as:

```
class A
{
   B b;
   C c;
}
```

But crashes if the class is laid out as:

```
class A
{
   C c;
   B b;
}
```

My first guess was that, of course b has to be created before c if I'm going to 
initialize c(b) in the constructor. I don't know if this is correct though. Is 
the constructor called *before* any member variables are allocated? Or are the 
member variables referenced in the constructor allocated first and then any remaining 
unreferenced member variables allocated at the end of the constructor (like for example if there was 
another member variable "C c2" that is unreferenced in the constructor)?

I am on Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way this works is that:

1. Construction of your object begins.
2. non-virtual base classes are constructed in order of declaration.
3. virtual base classes are constructed in order of declaration.
4. The current class part is created (initializing any vtable and such).
5. Member variables are constructed in order of appearance in the class declaration, not the initializer list.
6. Your constructor body is executed.
7. Construction of your object is complete.

I could be mistaken about the placement of #3, I rarely use virtual bases and rarely write code that depends on this stuff.  Why?  Because it's complicated and such code is extremely fragile.

Destruction happens in exactly the opposite order.

Answer (score 1):

Your members are initialized in the order they appear in your class definition. In your second example, b hasn't been initialized when you initialize c.

My compiler warns me if I put them out of order in the member initializers.

Comment: Ah ok. So all member variables are referenced at the top of the constructor call (even if it's not explicitly initialized) in exactly the order they appear in the class definition? Like for example, the constructor is essentially A::A():b(),c(b){} in the first example even if I don't explicitly put the "b()" there?

Comment: The answer is correct, however, you probably should make a distinction between object construction and object initialization.

Comment: @chris: Out of curiosity, which compiler are you using? I'm on VS2010 and didn't get one which would have helped me track down my problem quicker.

Comment: @JesseGood, good point. I don't have a particularly effective explanation at the moment.

Comment: @coderunner, GCC 4.6.2. I'm pretty sure it does this. I know it does if I switch the order. I also believe this is with `-WeffC++` or whatever the flag is.

Answer (score 1):

Members are always constructed in the order of declaration inside the class.

Thus:

```
class A
{
   B b;
   C c;
}
```

Works fine as you are passing b after it has been fully constructed.
While if you do this:

```
class A
{
   C c;
   B b;
}
```

Then you are constructing C using a B that has not been constructed. If you are passing by value this will break the copy constructor probably. If you pass by reference then if it is used inside the C constructor then it is using an un-initialized object of type 'B'

Answer (score 1):

The order of the constructor-class depends on the order inside your class definition. The second example does not work because class B constructor was not called yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, you said:

> I have a class "A", that has two member variables of type "B", "C". "C" has to be initiated with a member of type "B". So the constructor has to be:

But your code:

```
A::A()
: c(b) 
{
}
```

Says initialize `c` with the member variable `b`, not the *type* of `B` as your wording says.

Maybe you want:

```
A::A()
: c(B()) 
{
}
```

instead?

Comment: Doesn't "*member* of type B" mean the same thing (as opposed to "type B")? Want to make sure I'm not missing something semantically here.

Comment: Just saw your edit. Nope, the way the program is set up I need b and c as member variables.